# Box2D rotating away from planet

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx, box2d

So i am trying to get my player body to rotate away however when on the the lower half of the planet the rotation is inverted, im using `.setTransform()` for the rotation.

```
if(insideRotation==Math.abs(playerRotation)){

        } else if(insideRotation<Math.abs(playerRotation)){
            insideRotation+=Math.PI/45;
        } else if (insideRotation>Math.abs(playerRotation)){
            insideRotation-=Math.PI/45;
}
```

[image: Facing the wrong way]

[image: Facing the righ way]

The line on the block shows the way it is facing, i would like the bottom picture to be facing away from the green circle.

Comment: Could you attach some image with explanation what are trying to achieve? Also what are insideRotation/playerRotation variables?

Comment: `insideRotation` is a variable i use to create smooth automatic turning using `insideRotation+or-=Math.PI/45` every tick.
`playerRotation` is equal to `Math.atan2(chars[0].getCenterY()-planets[0].getCenterY(), (chars[0].getCenterX()-planets[0].getCenterX()))` Basically the desired angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a body always turned away from planet center you can just set it rotation of vector being subtraction result between body center and planet center.

It would be something like

```
    Body body, planet; //your 'character' and planet

    ...

    Vector2 bodyCenter = body.getWorldCenter();
    Vector2 planetCenter = planet.getWorldCenter(); //if you would use getPosition it would be related to the body's origin!

    Vector2 subVector = bodyCenter.sub( planetCenter );

    body.setTransform(x, y, subVector.angle() ); //it is possible that you will need to make '-angle()' here or something!
```

This way you will have always "fixed to planet" rotation no matter what position on planet will body have.